# Ruby/Selenium Opening URLs In Same Chrome Tab Instead Of Different Tabs

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, selenium

I am currently writing a program where I need to open two tabs in Chrome with Selenium/Ruby. Both tabs will hold a different url. So far, I have the following code:

```
$driver.navigate.to "CHROME EXTENSION URL"
body = $driver.find_element(:tag_name => 'body')
body.send_keys(:control, 't')
sleep 15
$driver.navigate.to "WEB BROWSER URL"
```

Two tabs are created but when I try to invoke $driver.navigate.to "WEB BROWSER URL" , the browser opens the [WEB BROWSER URL] in the first tab where the Chrome extension is. Does anyone know a way to get the two urls in their own respective tabs? Please let me know if I need to provide additional details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open a link in a new tab:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome

driver.navigate.to "https://www.google.com"

# open a new tab and set the context
driver.execute_script "window.open('_blank', 'tab2')"
driver.switch_to.window "tab2"

driver.get "http://stackoverflow.com/"
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you

Comment: if you're using Selenium 4 you can use `driver.switch_to.new_window(:tab)`